# Настройка первого запуска в расширении chrome

Tags: google-chrome

При нажатии на иконку моего расширения, в chrome, появляется всплывающее окно со стартовой страницей, которое загружается с урл. Пытаюсь создать "первый запуск" расширения, при котором первый запуск расширения будет отправлять юзера на основной урл, а последующие на другой. Как я могу это сделать?

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Title",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "1.24",
    /*"options_page": "settings.html",*/

    "icons": {
        "128": "images/icon.png"
      },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "128": "images/icon.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "background.html",
        "default_title": "Title"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "background"
    ],

    "background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": true
    }
}
```

Comment: пишите в localstorage переменную

Comment: Сделать background скрипт который после перехода по первому url запомнит это где нибудь в localStorage и в последующие нажатия уже будет это видеть и переходить по другому. Или если в бакграунде работать не удобно, можно воспользоваться https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage Ну и как вариант, если переход идет по url на внешний сайт и он вам доступен, то опознать пользователя на стороне сайта и показывать разное содержимое на одном url или сделать редирект для тех кто первый раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже миллион вопросов было такого типа

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(data){
    if(data.reason == "install"){
    //действие на интсалл
    }
});
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled тут все написано

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться